# Restrict endpoint to specific caller

Tags: ssl, asp.net-mvc-4, apigee

I'm working with an old legacy app at work that's written in ASP.NET 4. We recently started migrating to the cloud and we had to expose one of the endpoints so that our api gateway (Apigee) can call it. What is the correct way to restrict this endpoint so that it only allows calls from Apigee? I'm aware 2-way-ssl should solve this issue but that requires changes on the Apigee side and we don't have control over that. Is there something I can do on the API side to confirm that the certificate in the request is specifically from Apigee?

Answer (score 0):

You're describing the need for what is sometimes called 'southbound' authentication. Specifically mutual-TLS sometimes called *client* authentication, as opposed to *standard* (or one-way) TLS where only the server is being authenticated by the calling client. You're right: mTLS (a.k.a., "two-way SSL") is one means to allow your back-end server to authenticate the calling Apigee-layer 'client'.

When you want client authentication via TLS (mTLS) you need to configure your back-end server endpoint to *require* mTLS at the time of the handshake, and to have stored in its Truststore the signing CA certificate of the client certificate you expect to see offered up by the calling client at time of connection. Done right, your server

1. requires mTLS and shuts down the handshake if the client won't
   offer a client cert,
2. validates the client cert is authentic as being issued by a recognized signing CA (Truststore), and
3. is the actual client cert expected to be seen (e.g., by matching the expected distinguished name).

Here's an authoritative support-community article about doing all this, within Apigee: https://community.apigee.com/questions/63337/mutual-tls-between-client-to-edge-and-edge-to-back.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I'm pretty new to certificate authentication and cloud tools in general so I just want to make sure I understand correctly. 

To implement what I need:
    1. Get the Apigee certificate and have it added to our server's trusted store.
    2. Require SSL in our legacy app via something like this: 
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working- 
       with-ssl-in-web-api
    3. Validate certificate is from Apigee based on the distinguished name from inside 
        our app.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. Good recap. While I'm not an Microsoft-centric guy myself, those docs do look like appropriate ones for an ASP.NET webapp. Note that other practitioners may suggest other non-mTLS means to accomplish the same senior goal (authenticate the Apigee client), such as use of a signed JSON Web Token ('JWT'), but in your case, personally, I think the stated mTLS plan you outlined is prudent. And reiterate: definitely do study those Apigee Support comments from 2.5 years ago, which I linked to.